# 2001 Jeep Wrangler wiring part for headlight switch

Tags: jeep, wiring, wrangler

[image]

I'm wondering what this part is called? My headlights stopped working so I pulled the dash panel under the steering wheel and found this part was corroded and burnt. Please help me out! Headlights won't turn on

Comment: are you sure that's not an integral part of the switch assembly?

Answer (score 1):

That is called a headlight switch connector. :)

Comment: Thank you! Anyone know if there is a discount website I could find one at?

Comment: I would check junkyards.  I remember hearing from someone that worked at a dealership that the switch burning up wasn't uncommon and the fix was to relay the headlights.

Comment: Consider ch3cking the switch as well. If you have that much damage on the connector, the switch is likely damaged too.